React Button Component custom classname
I have a React Button Component like that
// src/components/Button.jsx
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styles from './Button.module.css';
import classNames from 'classnames';


const Button = ({
    onClick,
    children,
    type = 'button',
    variant = 'primary',
    disabled = false,
    customWidth,
    customHeight,          // New prop for custom width
    customBgColor,         // New prop for custom background color
    customTextColor,       // New prop for custom text color
    customBorderRadius,     // New prop for custom border radius
    className  // New prop for additional class


}) => {
    // const buttonClass = `${styles.button} ${styles[variant]} ${className}`; // Add the custom class
    const buttonClass = classNames(styles.button, styles[variant], className); // Combine internal and custom classes


    // const buttonClass = `${styles.button} ${styles[variant]}`;
    // Set the background color based on the disabled state
    const backgroundColor = disabled ? "#cccccc" : customBgColor || ''; // Default background color when not disabled

    // Inline styles for customization
    const style = {
        width: customWidth || '100%',  // Default to 100% if no width is provided
        height: customHeight || '',
        backgroundColor,
        color: customTextColor || '',  // Use provided text color or default to empty
        borderRadius: customBorderRadius || '5px', // Use provided border radius or default
    };

    return (
        <button
            type={type}
            className={buttonClass}
            onClick={onClick}
            disabled={disabled}
            style={style} // Apply custom styles here
        >
            {children}
        </button>
    );
};

// Add PropTypes validation
Button.propTypes = {
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    type: PropTypes.string,
    variant: PropTypes.string,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    customWidth: PropTypes.string,        // New prop for custom width
    customHeight: PropTypes.string,
    customBgColor: PropTypes.string,      // New prop for custom background color
    customTextColor: PropTypes.string,    // New prop for custom text color
    customBorderRadius: PropTypes.string, // New prop for custom border radius
    className: PropTypes.string, // New prop for additional class

};



export default Button;


This Button Component in the App.jsx file used like that
< Header >
          <FalshyContainer>
            <Username username={username} />
            {!isQuestionPageVisible && (
              <Button
                className={styles.customButton} // Apply the custom class here
                onClick={handleContactUs}
                customWidth="100px"
                customHeight="40px"
                customBgColor="white"
                customTextColor="black"
                customBorderRadius="5px"
              >
                Contact Us
              </Button>
            )}
 </FalshyContainer>
< /Header >



And here also a customButton class name in the FalshyContainer.module.css here
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .customButton {
     background-color: red;
    }
  }


I am trying to achieve that this customButton class name like that
 className={styles.customButton}
should apply to the Button which i am using as a children in the FalshyContainer.
But this style does not apply .

what is the content of styles.customButton? could you upload a sample of your project in an online code editor like codesandbox or stackblitz and share it here?

Please use this syntax in this criteria, styles.customButton is only accessible with in the component where it's imported.
the custom class customButton is in the FalshyContainer.module.css, we need to ensure the scope from the style is applied in the Button
App.jsx file here:
import FalshyContainerStyles from './FalshyContainer.module.css'; // Import FalshyContainer styles

< Header >
    <FalshyContainer>
    <Username username={username} />
    {!isQuestionPageVisible && (
        <Button
        className={styles.customButton} // Apply the custom class here
        onClick={handleContactUs}
        customWidth="100px"
        customHeight="40px"
        customBgColor="white"
        customTextColor="black"
        customBorderRadius="5px"
        >
        Contact Us
        </Button>
    )}
    </FalshyContainer>
< /Header >

We have Importing Styles: styles.customButton is defined in FalshyContainer.module.css, the styles are scoped to that file. You need to import FalshyContainer.module.css where you are applying the className
